# how to get Libre Office to adjust row height to accommodate text entry?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I need for LibreOffice to automatically adjust row height for text entries.

I have tried to acomplish this by checking the *wrap text* option, which I thought would be the solution, but it is not.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 15):

Using LibreOffice Calc 5.4.4.2 on OS X, I found I had to do **four** things to set every row to its optimum height:

1. Select all cells
2. In the "Format" menu, turn on "Format/Text/Wrap Text"
3. In the "Format" menu, choose "Format/Rows/Optimal Height...", and in the resulting dialog set "Add" to "0.0" and turn on the "Default" checkbox
4. Add and then remove an empty column.

That last step sometimes isn't necessary, but at times LibreOffice will refuse to recalculate the row heights until you dope-slap it into submission.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel. Exactly what I'm looking for! :)

Comment: Everytime I change text, I have to reset height to 0.0

Comment: My god! This works! I can't believe it! It's half an hour that I try to auto-set optimal width for all columns! Just setting 0.0 default in optimal width did the trick! Thanks man!

Comment: Seconding Adam's comment. Selecting all rows + invoking the Optimal Height dialog box does adjust the row heights properly, but only once. It doesn't fix the underlying problem, which is that the rows don't auto-adjust.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do both:

Format cells.... / Alignment / Wrap text automatically

and

Select the concerning cells or entire rows: right click on selected row numbers and choose 'optimal row height'

Part of the solution I found [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/9348/calc-restore-row-heights-to-automatic-to-max-content-height/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you must have one or other, or both, "Default" not ticked in Height/Optimal Height under Format Row.

Answer (score 0):

I followed Daniel Griscom's answer but after adjusting cell contents you may have to Alt+Shift+Arrow Key (Optimizes the column width or row height based on the current cell).

Source: https://help.libreoffice.org/6.2/en-US/text/scalc/04/01020000.html

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1185284)

Comment: If someone wants to add this answer as a comment I could care less if it gets deleted. This is an answer to the comments of the accepted answer and it works